# Changing hidden to visible state of Table > TR on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a table with almost 100 rows, I'm displaying 20 as default by adding a class to the tr as **visible** and hiding the rest of rows by the class **hidden**

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="visible"></tr>
    <tr class="visible"></tr>
    <tr class="hidden"></tr>
    <tr class="hidden"></tr>
    <tr class="hidden"></tr>
</tbody>
```

I've added an **Add More** button to display 5 rows each time the button is clicked but my jQuery logic is completely wrong, Have a look at it

```
$(".more-show").click(function (e)  {
    e.preventDefault();
    for (var i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        $('#ranking-table tr').each(function(i) {
            $(this).removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
        });
    }
});
```

---

### PROBLEM

Instead of displaying 5 rows each time upon click and it has to be the very first 5 **hidden** rows, It's displaying all the rows by changing the class to **visible**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the selector `$('#ranking-table tr.hidden:lt(5)')` to select the first 5 `tr` elements with class `.hidden`. It makes use of [`:lt(5)`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/uLsam4rs/)

```
$(".more-show").click(function (e)  {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#ranking-table tr.hidden:lt(5)').each(function(i) {
        $(this).removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
    });
});
```